# New google authentication system 2022

Tags: javascript, google-signin

I am planning to use new google login button to my website.

This is code I used:

```
 <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="___.apps.googleusercontent.com">
    
    <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>
    
    <a href="#" onclick="signOut();">Sign out</a>
    

<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
    <script>
            
            
            function onSignIn( googleUser ) {
                    var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
                    console.log( 'ID: ' + profile.getId() ); // Do not send to your backend! Use an ID token instead.
                    console.log( 'Name: ' + profile.getName() );
                    console.log( 'Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl() );
                    console.log( 'Email: ' + profile.getEmail() ); // This is null if the 'email' scope is not present.
                }
            function signOut() {
                var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
                auth2.signOut().then( function () {
                    console.log( 'User signed out.' );
                } );
            }
        </script>
```

But now this is not working.

I have changed JS library to this

```
<script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>
```

Also remove META tag add following code:

```
<div id="g_id_onload"
         data-client_id="YOUR_CLIENT_ID"
         data-callback="handleCredentialResponse">
    </div>
    <div class="g_id_signin" data-type="standard"></div>
```

Reference: https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/migration

But now show following errors:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is what i use to login and get Google-User information.

**Javascript part -> add it to your HEAD element**

```
<script>
(function(d, s, id){
 var js, gjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
 if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
 js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
 js.src = 'https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client';
 gjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, gjs);
}(document, 'script', 'google-jssdk'));

window.onSignIn = (response) => {
    const sData = response.credential.split(".");
    const gData = JSON.parse(atob(sData[1]));
    //console.log(gData);
    console.log("Email: "+gData.email);
    console.log("Email-verified: "+gData.email_verified);
    console.log("Firstname: "+gData.given_name);
    console.log("Lastname: "+gData.family_name);
    console.log("IMG-url: "+gData.picture);
}
</script>
```

**Html part -> add it to your BODY element**

```
<!-- Showing the 'Login whith Google' on Pageload in a seperate fixed content box -->
<div id="g_id_onload"
     data-client_id="YOUR_GOOGLE_APP_ID"
     data-callback="onSignIn"
>
</div>

<!-- The button - need Click/Tab action -->
<div class="g_id_signin" 
     data-size="small"
     data-width="22"
     data-client_id="YOUR_GOOGLE_APP_ID" 
     data-type="standard"  
     data-callback="onSignIn"
>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Check your Google Auth its your origin issue and second use

```
 <script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>
    <body>
    
    <div id="g_id_onload"
         data-client_id="your_client_id"
         data-callback="handleCredentialResponse">
    </div>



    <div class="g_id_signin" data-client_id="your_client_id" data-type="standard"  data-callback="handleCredentialResponse">

    </div>



window.handleCredentialResponse = (response) => {

console.log(response)
  


  }
```